# Why Rep() function only giving me a single value vector?

Tags: r

I wrote the code;

rep(1, length(8))

but I am getting result:
[image]

what can be the cause?

Comment: You probably intend `rep(1, 8)`. Check out what `length(8)` returns.

Comment: `length(8)` is actually 1...

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `length()`:

```
rep(1, 8)
```